# How to pass values from custom PageRenderer to Shared Xaml Page code behind in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, custom-renderer

I have a Xamarin page in which I had to use Android native page renderer in order to support platform specific API.

`BasePage.xaml` passes control to `MyPage.xaml` with `Navigation.PushAsync()`

**XAML page : MyPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Views.MyPage" Title="My Page">
    <ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Android Custom page renderer** for the above is something like below.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyPage), typeof(MyPageRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class MyPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        private Context _localContext;
        private global::Android.Views.View view;

        private Activity activity;
        public event EventHandler ItemAdded;

        public MyPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _localContext = context;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                SetupUserInterface();
                SetupEventHandlers();
                AddView(view);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"ERROR: ", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void SetupUserInterface()
        {
            activity = this.Context as Activity;
            view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.axml_layout, this, false);

        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
            var msw = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(r - l, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
            var msh = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(b - t, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);

            view.Measure(msw, msh);
            view.Layout(0, 0, r - l, b - t);
        }

        private void SetupEventHandlers()
        {
            //blah blah
        }

        private void ButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //do something
            //Here Navigate back to page which triggered this with outcome parameter or some event 
            ItemAdded(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        }


    }
}
```

My intention is send back control to `MyPage.xaml.cs` or `BasePage.xaml.cs` from `MyPageRenderer` with outcome of **`ButtonTapped`**.I am using event `ItemAdded` and handle it in code behind of that page. I can not access `ItemAdded` event which is in android specific renderer only from shared project.

I have to update `ViewModel` of `BasePage` so that I update the content of the items there when MyPage has been popped after adding new item by back button.

**Problem:**
I can access MyPage and BasePage but can not access renderer method and variables from Shared project because Android project depends on shared not vice versa.

**I have to do something like below** which is working for *non-native render page*
**BasePage:**

```
    var myPage = new MyPage();
    myPage.ItemAdded += OnItemAdded;
    await Navigation.PushAsync(myPage);
```

**MyPage:**

```
public event EventHandler ItemAdded;
.
.

void SomeMethod(){

ItemAdded(this, EventArgs.Empty);

}
```

**Question:** How do we pass control from NativeRenderer back to Xamarin Forms shared code?

I know we can pass control to `MainActivity` class but I want to pass control to `BasePage.xaml.cs` which I did not get from documentation. If anyone has worked on PageRenderer please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in "MyPage" Class

```
  public class MyPage : ContentPage
    {
        public void RaiseSomeButtonClicked() => OnSomeButtonClickeded();

        private void OnSomeButtonClicked()
        {
            //by using aggregators you can publish any event and subscribe it in you BasePage.xaml.cs 
            ((App)App.Current).Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>()
                .GetEvent<SomeButtonClickedEvent>().Publish(new SomeButtonClickedEvent());
        }
    }
```

in "MyPageRenderer" Class :

```
public class MyPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        MyPage myPage;
        //...
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            myPage = (MyPage)e.NewElement;
            //...
        }
        private void ButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //do something
            myPage.RaiseSomeButtonClicked();

        }
    }
```

in "BasePage.xaml.cs", subscribe this event.

```
public partial class BasePage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly SubscriptionToken _SomeButtonClickedEventSubscription;

    public BasePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _SomeButtonClickedEventSubscription = eventAggregator.Value.GetEvent<SomeButtonClickedEvent>().SubscribeAsync(async e =>
    {
        //anything you want to do when button clicked!

    }, threadOption: ThreadOption.UIThread, keepSubscriberReferenceAlive: true);
    }
}
```

You should define Your event class in this way:

```
public class SomeButtonClickedEvent : PubSubEvent<SomeButtonClickedEvent>
    {
        //you can define parameters here, if the event needs to pass a parameter.
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! , I couldnt resolve `(App)App.Current).Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>()` I used simple code based on your approach. It worked.

Comment: You’re right, I forgot to mention that my code is base on xamarin.forms and Prism.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to [zohre moradi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7818699)'s answer I could achieve this as below.
This does not use  `IEventAggregator` -`Subscribe/Publish` of events methods. If event is only required at one page `IEventAggregator` can be avoided.

**MyPage.xaml.cs**

```
public event EventHandler ItemAdded;

public void RaiseItemAdded()
{
    ItemAdded(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}


//have to close return call back after item addition in MyPage  
public async void CallPopAsync()
{
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

**MyPageRenderer.cs**

```
MyPage mypage;

protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    mypage= (MyPage)e.NewElement;

    if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        SetupUserInterface();
        SetupEventHandlers();
        AddView(view);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"ERROR: ", ex.Message);
    }
}       

private void ButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something

    myPage.RaiseItemAdded();

    //notify
    Toast.MakeText(this.Context, "Item created", ToastLength.Long).Show();

    myPage.CallPopAsync();      
}
```

And in **BasePage.xaml.cs**

```
//in some method    
var myPage = new MyPage();
myPage.ItemAdded += OnItemAdded;
await Navigation.PushAsync(myPage);

private void OnItemAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //call method to update binding object of viewmodel
}
```